# Equivalent topologies on the Tate Module

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, topological-groups, profinite-groups

This is a question from Chapter III, section 7 of Silverman's *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*. The section introduces the Tate module and then the author makes the offhand remark:

> Since each $E[\ell^n]$ is a $\mathbb{Z}/\ell^n\mathbb{Z}$-module, we see that the Tate module has a natural structure as a $\mathbb{Z}_\ell$-module. Further, since the multiplication-by-$\ell$ maps are surjective, the inverse limit topology on $T_\ell(E)$ is equivalent to the $\ell$-adic topology that it gains by being a $\mathbb{Z}_\ell$-module.

I'm having trouble understanding this comment. I see that the Tate module is a $\mathbb{Z}_\ell$-module, since $\mathbb{Z}_\ell$ can act component-wise on the Tate module. For the topology, I assume that the inverse limit topology means the subspace topology that $T_\ell(E)$ inherits as a subspace of $\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} E[\ell^n]$, with each $E[\ell^n]$ given the discrete topology. What is the topology that $\mathbb{Z}_\ell$ gains by being a $\mathbb{Z}_\ell$-module, and why does the surjectivity of the multiplication-by-$\ell$ maps imply that these two topologies are equivalent?

Comment: By construction of $T_\ell(E)$ as $\varprojlim E[\ell^n]$ the topology inherited from (the product topology on) $\prod E[\ell^n]$ is the same as $\varprojlim T_\ell(E)/\ell^n T_\ell(E)$ which is of course the same as the $\Bbb{Z}_\ell \varprojlim= \Bbb{Z}/\ell^n \Bbb{Z}$-module topology

Comment: Thanks for the response, I think I'm missing some background. What do you mean by the "$\mathbb{Z}_\ell \varinjlim = \mathbb{Z}/\ell^n \mathbb{Z}$-module topology"?

Comment: I think what he means is $\mathbb{Z}_\ell = \varprojlim \mathbb{Z}/\ell^n\mathcal{Z}$.

Comment: Sure, but what is the topology that the Tate module inherits as a $\varprojlim \mathbb{Z} / \ell^n \mathbb{Z}$ module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got stuck at this part too. The important part of Silverman's last sentence is the term $l$-adic:
The $l$-adic topology of $\mathbb{Z}_l$ has a basis given by the sets

\begin{equation}
x + l^n \mathbb{Z}_l
\end{equation}

with $x \in \mathbb{Z}_l$.

Now the Tate module has a natural $l$-adic topology because it is a module over $\mathbb{Z}_l. It can be defined by choosing the basis

\begin{equation}
P + l^n \mathbb{Z}_l T_l(E)
\end{equation}

for $P \in T_l(E)$.

Let us analyse what these sets look like. Write $P = (P_1, P_2, \ldots)$ with $P_i \in E[l^i]$ for all $i$. For an element $a \in \mathbb{Z}_l$ we write $a_i = a \mod l^i$. Then

\begin{equation}
a P = (a_i P_i)_i.
\end{equation}

Since the $a_i$ are compatible, this is again an element of $T_l(E)$.
If $a \in l^n \mathbb{Z}_l$, then $a P = (P_1, P_2, \ldots, P_{n-1}, a_n P_n, a_{n+1} P_n+1, \ldots)$. So the set consists of all points in $T_l(E)$ where we fix the first $n-1$ elements and let the rest vary within the confines of $T_l(E)$ (i.e., we still want $[l] P_k = P_{k-1}$ for all $k$).

Now look at the definition of the inverse limit topology. The open sets are of the form $V \cap T_l(E)$, where $V \subseteq \prod_n E[l^n]$ is open in the product topology.
Let $\pi_i: \prod_n E[l^n] \to E[l^i]$ be the projection. Then $V$ is a union of intersections of sets of the form $\pi_i^{-1}(U_i)$, where $U_i \subseteq E[l^i]$ is open. Since we picked the discrete topology on $E[l^i]$, the $U_i$ are thus arbitrary.

This boils down to including points $P = (P_n)_n$ in an open set such that $P_i \in U_i$ for a bunch of $i$ and the rest are arbitrary, then intersecting with $T_l(E)$. To get a basis of this topology, we just choose open sets with $U_i$ being one points sets. This boils down further to simply fixing $P_1$ to $P_{n-1}$ for some $n$ and letting the rest vary, which is precisely the $l$-adic topology we saw earlier.

So the two topologies are the same.

I don't know why it's explicitly stated that the multiplication-by-l maps are surjective -- but all of these constructiosn just don't really make sense if this isn't the case. "Letting the rest of the points vary" uses precisely the surjectivity, since if we construct an element of $T_l(E)$ and pick a point $P_n$, then we are able to find a compatible point $P_{n+1}$ and so forth.